# Sequelize logging both query and output

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have seen examples where you could log the sql query using the options logging function in sequelize models such as below:

```
    logging: message => {
        console.log(message);
    }
```

Is there an example of logging the result that comes back from executing the SQL query instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can define at the time of db connection.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    logging: console.log
    logging: function (data) {
    }
});
```

// In this function, you can do your logic.

```
logging: function (str) {}
```

// Or you can use in this way using console.log upon model query:

```
User.find(1, { logging: console.log })
```

Comment: can you log the values that is returned as well e.g. users = [{ id: '123', name: 'John Doe'}]?